# Android Error : IPerf::tryGetService failed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, iperf

I am developing a simple Android app. In my app I implement a toolbar and an actionbar with a `ViewPager` for doing swipe between fragments, I am using a `RecyclerView` to fill a list of movie and everything goes fine.

The app doesn't crash but in the `Log Cat` appears a constant error every time I am scrolling over the list and swiping between fragments and I notice that my app runs slowly and has a terrible user experience.

[image]

Comment: Any luck by figuring out what is going wrong by using the official profiler in Android Studio?

Comment: The slowly behavior is more likely because of [How you fetch the recyclerView], as I understood u should be fetching data from internet to recyclerView, does it happen in background ?. what library u use for requesting data ?. do you request all data items or just the first 10 items and when scroll another 10 items are requested ?

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce this same behaviour on other devices/emulators? In my experience some android devices tend to be quite verbose when it comes to errors not specifically related to application code.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code?

Comment: `IPerf` is not responsible for your slow app perfomance.Make `Recyclerview` smooth scrollable and use ` android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` inside your recyclerview.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @MohamedEmbaby hi, I am getting same error and I am using volley and yes, I am facing 20 objects at a time.

Comment: @Ancee request 10 items and when user scroll to last item request 10 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To use the JNI, or not to use the JNI (Android performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031567/to-use-the-jni-or-not-to-use-the-jni-android-performance)

Answer (score 1):

```
E/ANDR-PERF: IPerf::tryGetService failed!
```

I also got the above error too, but after a while, I realized that it was occurring because my code was trying to get some data from an API.

I hope this might give some idea to you, I know it's too late to answer but it might be helpful for those who are searching and land here.

Best regards.

Comment: that it was occurring because my code was trying to get some data from an API??? this is what i want my code to do do you say that i have to stop fetch data from the api to make this error disappear?

Comment: No, I just mentioned the reason of the error. 
It means fetching fails because of wrong link/credentials or slow connections between them. It might even caused by another reason but code might be reviewed for that. 
Sorry I don't remember how i solved mine; It was jun '19.
@Sideeg MoHammed